# How to properly use environment variables from k8s inside application.properties in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I’m trying to set some environment variables in k8s deployment and use them within the `application.properties` in my spring boot application, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong because spring is not reading those variables, although when checking the `env vars` on the pod, all the vars are set correctly.

The error log from the container:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_URL}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER_NAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: .../api
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: DB_URL
            value: "posgres"
          - name: DB_NAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: postgres-config
                key: dbName
          - name: DB_USER_NAME
            valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: dbUserName
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: dbPassword
```

Comment: need more information to know the root cause. one possible reason might be you mis-used database operations code.  You can try 1.simply print those vars in java code first. 2. hardcode  the vars in properties file.

Comment: you are missed : `- name: DB_URL value: "posgres"` is your service name is `posgres` or `postgres` ?

Comment: Does your `java -jar` command work outside the docker file, and pick up environment variables?

Comment: Is this the default `application.properties` or are you using a special profile? I'm asking because what you write sounds like the ENVs are set, but the spring profile that uses these ENVs is not active. If you're using a special profile, check the logs of spring boot and take a look at the active profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DockerFile was wrong.
Everything is working fine after changing the DockerFile to this:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11-slim as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .

COPY src/ /app/src/
RUN mvn install -DskipTests=true

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.8_10-alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/target/*.jar /app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Comment: so which part of your dockfile is wrong? how you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `env:` in your deployment.yaml, see here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

if you have **kubectl** installed you can check how env vars must be declared by doing an explain like follow : `kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.containers`

Comment: I'm sorry the copy past was wrong.
The 'env:' is there (I've edited the question )